# Space between a|b in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, formatting, grammar

For a context free grammar I need to write:

```
A -> a | b
```

My code for this is

```
$ A \rightarrow a | b $
```

however this gives me something like

```
A -> a|b // wanted: a | b, note the space before and after the |
```

meaning there is no space between a|b.

How can I fix this?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Use `\mid` that will produce the same spacing as `\rightarrow`

Comment: works perfect, thanks! Please add it as answer.